# trying to run the spring boot embedded web container on hadoop cluster

Tags: spring, hadoop, spring-boot

I am trying to run a spring boot embedded web container application that needs to talk to hdfs. I have included the spring data hadoop in my pom.xml but when I run the application on the cluster i get this error

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: JAR entry lib/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar!/core-default.xml not found in hdfspub-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
at .jar.JarURLConnec...ction.java:122)
at JarURLConnec...ction.java:132)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityM anager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:65 1)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersion Detector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.ja va:186)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Co nfiguration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:772)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Co nfiguration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLPars er.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMPars er.parse(DOMParser.java:232)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBu ilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBu ilder.java:180)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource( Configuration.java:1156)

Even thought if I look at my jar I can see that hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar is there

$ unzip -l hdfspub-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar
4203713 10-25-2013 21:04 lib/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: it seems like spring boot loader is not picking up configuration files in the hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar jar file

Comment: I am really stuck on this. I would appreciate if I could get any help on this.

Comment: Can you open an issue on [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues), please?

Comment: @adeelmahmood hi!, I have same problem :/, Do you have any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, solution is to add hadoop.core to your pom/build.gradle but you have to exclude from spring.data.hadoop and apache.hadoop groups:

- tomcat
- org.mortbay.jetty
- javax.servlet

my build.gradle:

```
   compile('org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:1.2.1'){
       exclude group: 'org.mortbay.jetty'
       exclude group: 'javax.servlet'
       exclude group: 'tomcat'       
   }
   compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-hadoop:1.0.2.RELEASE') {
       exclude group: 'org.mortbay.jetty'
       exclude group: 'javax.servlet'
       exclude group: 'tomcat'
   }
```